# Magento index status pending forever

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, indexing, magento-1.7

I've created a Magento instance via command line and added a few products. Right after, started the re-index proccess for every indexes. The current situation is that all indexes have status *pending/processing*. 
This situation brings me a few questions:

1. Is there any relation between this problem and the installation process? (via command line)
2. Is it a problem? Since I didn't have noticed any side effect I'm  not very concerned about it. Unless if it's spending tons of unnecessary processing.
3. How can I fix it?

I've already executed `php shell/indexer.php reindexall` but nothing changed. And, if I execute `php shell/indexer.php --status` all indexes report as 'Pending'.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First: You'll want to get your terminology straight.  (it can be a little confusing).  A Magento index has one of three statuses.

```
pending
working
require_reindex
```

You can see the constants for these statuses here

```
const STATUS_RUNNING            = 'working';
const STATUS_PENDING            = 'pending';
const STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX    = 'require_reindex';
```

This can be confusing because the image Magento uses to represent these statuses use different terminology.

[image]

That is, when an index has a status of `pending`, Magento's UI represents this as `Ready`.  When an index has a status of `working`, Magento's UI represents this as `Processing`, etc.

Further confusing things, the `indexer.php` command **does not** use this terminology -- instead it uses terms closer to the actual status

```
Pending
Require Reindex
Running
```

So, when you're saying Pending/Processing above, it's not clear what state your system is in.

Second: PHP does not have a built in queuing system — that means each index runs in an individual PHP process.  This also means Magento and PHP have no (easy, reliable) way to determine if an index process is running.  In order to implement the `STATUS_RUNNING`/`Working`/`Running` status, Magento uses lock files to keep track of an index's status.  These lock files are located in

```
var/locks/index_process_*
```

When an index is "stuck" in `STATUS_RUNNING`/`Working`/`Running` for longer than you'd expect, it's usually because

1. A indexer request quit half way though, and failed to clean up its log files
2. The permissions of the files in `var/locks/index_process_*` are such that PHP can't write the files

Re: #2 -- If you're in the habit of using the command line indexer, you can often end up creating files that Magento, when running from the web-server/web-admin, won't be able to edit or delete.  Deleting these files and then reindexing is often the best way to fix this problem.

Comment: Great! I believe the second tip (permission) is generating my problem.

Answer (score 1):

in var/locks folder  delete the .lock file which was created.

This will e the first step in solving.

Also check if php execution time and memory limit are not the reason for indexing script not completing its execution.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I don't believe PHP is limiting the execution (since the store is almost empty), but I'll check it out too. I'm assuming you don't believe there a link between mine installation process and the problem. Right?

Comment: when indexing starts in var/lock folders few lock files are placed by Magento.This is done so that no other code should run indexing on locked process.But in your case when indexing was run and lock file was placed as execution was not completed so lock file not removed.